# How to use Decrypt file with AES in Android

Tags: java, android, file, encryption

In my application I want to download an HTML file from server, then decrypt this file and show into webView!
The backend developer uses this library for encrypt file from server: https://github.com/soarecostin/file-vault

I wrote the code below, but when decrypting a file, it shows an error in Logcat and doesn't decrypt this file!

My code:

```
    encryptionPassword = "7BOF%aZQMpfJ#2wUS*S6!@K+ZB$Sz+J0";

    String inputFile = FileUtils.getDirPath(this) + "/BookFile_716798.html";
    String outPutFile = FileUtils.getDirPath(this) + "/BookFile_716798_decrypt.html";

    try {
        decrypt(inputFile, encryptionPassword, outPutFile);
        Log.e("DecryptLog", "0");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("DecryptLog", "1");
        Log.e("DecryptLog", "" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("DecryptLog", "2");
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("DecryptLog", "3");
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("DecryptLog", "4");
    }

private void decrypt(String path, String password, String outPath)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outPath);
    byte[] key = (password).getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    key = sha.digest(key);
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
        fos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    cis.close();
}
```

This message is shown in `logCat`:

```
2020-07-31 21:52:39.881 1367-1367/com.app.app E/DecryptLog: 1
2020-07-31 21:52:39.881 1367-1367/com.app.appE/DecryptLog: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: In yours today (closed) question we talked about 'AES-256-CBC' but your example code is 'AES-128-ECB' so please change your code that you are working with this (CBC) mode, thanks. Btw: you do not need to hash the key with SHA-1 and use Arrays.copy as your key is already a 32 byte long key when converted to byte array.

Comment: Oh, no, using CBC to copy a file over the internet? Please use TLS, clearly nobody has any idea what they are doing.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes , thanks my friend. but what is TLS?

Comment: SSL maybe more known to you? HTTPS?